# What changed in bootstrap 5 to make controls assume max size

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I recently upgraded NodeJs to 16.13.0 from 14.x. One of the modules updated was `bootstrap` of course. I also had to get rid of my `Jumbotron` control because of the upgrade, but I don't think that's part of the issue I am having. I have quite a few `<div>` controls with the className marked as 'row'. However, after the upgrade, 'row' is being ignored and all other controls are on separate lines with max width set to container width.

[image]

For example, in the image you can see my Totals control shows Subtotal with the subtotal value on the next line. My Totals component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { GetTotal } from './CartHandler';
import { formatter } from '../common.js'

import "./Checkout.scss"


export default function TotalsBlock(props) {
    let carttotal = GetTotal();
    let shipping = 10.57;
    let taxes = 4.93;


    return (
        <aside id="checkout" className="block col-1">
            <h1>Total</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <label>Subtotal</label>
                <label>{formatter.format(carttotal)}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <label>Shipping</label>
                <label>{formatter.format(shipping)}</label>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <label>Taxes</label>
                <label>{formatter.format(taxes)}</label>
            </div>
            <hr/>
            <div className="row">
                <label>Total</label>
                <label>{formatter.format(carttotal + shipping + taxes)}</label>
            </div>
        </aside>
    );
}
```

... and `Checkout.scss`:

```
#checkout {
    .row {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        justify-content: space-between;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: 0;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .col-1 {
        flex: 1;
        max-width: 33%;
    }

    .col-2 {
        flex: 2;
        max-width: 66%;
    }

    .header {
        background-color: cornflowerblue;        
        color: white;
    }

    .block {
        background-color: lightgray;
        padding: 1rem;
        margin: 0.5rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }

    .table-wrapper {
        max-height: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
    }

    th.price, th.quantity {
        width: 10%;
    }

    .table-extra {
    }
}
```

What changed in bootstrap 5 to not make 'row' work and why are my elements max size? I think these are both the same actual problem. Any help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

[image]

When I inspect with the Browser's DevTools .row width is set to 100%. I can uncheck it or set width to auto everything goes back to normal. However, I put `width: auto` in .row in the `Checkout.scss` it gets set to 100% anyway...

Comment: I'd bet that your rows and items are working perfectly and that ````className="block col-1"```` or something is limiting the widget size.  Should that be block col-1?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way I suppose...

I added:

```
.row > * {
    width: auto;
}
```

...to `Checkout.scss` to overwrite bootstrap. I am all ears if anyone has a better Solution.